# Let's get critical: Feb 2014 Site Self-Evaluation

Tags: discussion, site-evaluation

We all love [Sports Stack Exchange](http://sports.stackexchange.com), but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.

The [Site Self-Evaluation review queue](https://sports.stackexchange.com/review/site-eval) is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. 
Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.

Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? **Post an answer below to share your thoughts** and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Comment: No longer relevant as the site is out of beta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Final Results

- [Rule on Being fouled shooting at the wrong basket](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/3794/rule-on-being-fouled-shooting-at-the-wrong-basket)

**Net Score: 6** (Excellent: 7, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [Foosball five-man wall bounce rule](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/3809/foosball-five-man-wall-bounce-rule)

**Net Score: 6** (Excellent: 6, Satisfactory: 6, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Why there is no ICC rankings for women's test cricket?](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/3643/why-there-is-no-icc-rankings-for-womens-test-cricket)

**Net Score: 4** (Excellent: 5, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [When can a batsman change from batting left handed to right handed?](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/3696/when-can-a-batsman-change-from-batting-left-handed-to-right-handed)

**Net Score: 3** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 7, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Who can compete at Universiade?](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/3647/who-can-compete-at-universiade)

**Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 3)

---

- [What is the difference between a power slide and a hockey stop?](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/3674/what-is-the-difference-between-a-power-slide-and-a-hockey-stop)

**Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 10, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [Net run rate calculation if team batting 2nd scores more runs than the target?](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/3774/net-run-rate-calculation-if-team-batting-2nd-scores-more-runs-than-the-target)

**Net Score: -1** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 6, Needs Improvement: 3)

---

- [What happens if the non-striker, holding his gloves, drops one of them and the ball in play touches it?](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/3641/what-happens-if-the-non-striker-holding-his-gloves-drops-one-of-them-and-the-b)

**Net Score: -2** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 6, Needs Improvement: 4)

---

- [If a batsman is bowled off a free hit, can he still score any runs?](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/3759/cricket-match-results)

**Net Score: -2** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 4)

---

- [Are penalty shots counted in goalie's saves percentage and goal against average?](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/3758/are-penalty-shots-counted-in-goalies-saves-percentage-and-goal-against-average)

**Net Score: -5** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 7)

---

Comment: I am enthralled that a question, which was voted up seven times, was subjected to needing improvement seven times ([Are penalty shots counted in goalie's saves percentage and goal against average?](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/3758/are-penalty-shots-counted-in-goalies-saves-percentage-and-goal-against-average)). If we are [upvoting because the question is useful](https://sports.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-up), then why is there a discrepancy?

Comment: @edmastermind29 - The question is upvoted simply because it is a good question. But it was reviewed as *need improvement* just because it doesn't have any satisfactory answer. That's all. Self evaluation is not only for question's quality it is for both question and answers' quality. You can see the answers were not upvoted in that question as they were not satisfactory. The problem is that we can't evaluate question and answers separately in the self evaluation review queue.

Comment: The second paragraph tells me to review answers, and that's what I did. @edmastermind29 Your first comment: those were my thoughts exactly !! Having looked at the answer, I see it's long, but leaves (apparently) room for discussions. I hope I was the one that flagged it as "Needs Improvement"

Comment: I justed looked it up: http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/13855684#13855684

Comment: @edmastermind29 I think I just answered to the wrong question. You were referring to the penalty question?

Comment: ps: I'm talkinga bout: Rule on Being fouled shooting at the wrong basket. I'm now equally enthralled about that outcome !!

Comment: @hims056 Point taken. A part of my agenda here is to illustrate that good questions usually produce good answers...but less than adequate answers reflect on the question poorly...and vice-versa. I think this is a shame, and the conclusion is that questions AND answers contribute to quality content.

Comment: @JacobJanTuinstra I clarified in my original comment...but now that you bring up your point, I'm further interested...after looking at your [chat response](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/13855684#13855684), I would like to know what about the answer could be improved (outside of making it more concise in regards to the OPs question).

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me like some element of trivia questions or subjective/opinion questions creeps into the site steadily. Most of the time they seemed to get marked as such. Sometimes they get voted up and/or answered before they can be closed or dealt with. I try to handle these types of questions when I see them mod-flagged.

I think there is generally a good question-to-answer ratio on the site and most questions do not go very long without an answer.

We seem to be getting a fairly regular amount of questions about cricket and sports that are less popular in the United States, which IMO is good - it would seem to indicate the site is drawing people from outside the US.

Comment: +1 However, [this is nothing new](http://meta.sports.stackexchange.com/a/363/527) and your answer supports that site activity is similar compared to May 2013 (although, we are getting more daily visits). If anything is to be taken from this, voting may not be the best indicator of reasonably off-topic questions (and/or users are unaware of what's off-topic), but the community is free to use their voting privileges how they please. Even after a question is marked as answered, the [question can still be closed](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/3746/calves-muscles-pain-when-running).

Answer (score 0):

It seems like a lot of questions are about rules, and the answers are merely copy/paste from official rulebooks, or links to the rulebooks.  Maybe this is ok though?

Comment: What do you recommend? That may be a majority of our questions, but some do tend to go beyond general reference (eg, if A happens, how do the rules enforce situation A?).

Comment: Yeah, very true.  Unfortunately I don't really have any recommendations about how to fix that (or honestly, if it really needs to be "fixed").  So much about sports is rules interpretation; I don't think there's much we can do about it.  Since I'm not really providing an answer, I should probably downvote my response. :)

Comment: No, this is an accurate observation. The issue isn't "rules interpretation" but "[you can only get so far with...rules questions](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/12339600#12339600)."

Answer (score 0):

I think I've noticed a drop in the answered questions percentage from 98% to 94%.

Comment: Still a high percentage. This reveals the possibility that some questions are being asked and we do not (yet) have the expertise in place to answer it. This isn't entirely the case, but is one factor that I wouldn't deem a concern.

Comment: @edmastermind29 Well, I just wanted to say something. Have the number of questions increased as well?

Thanks for responding though !!

Comment: Eyeballing it, it seems like we've had bursts of question asking. Can't say the median number has been going up (per Area 51), but it seems like there has been a variety of content coming in.